# Service Fabric requirements to RunAs a domain user

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We are new to Service Fabric and it looks really promising however we are having a surprising amount of trouble trying to run a simple stateless service as a domain user. We are running a stand-alone windows cluster on-prem using our local domain.

We have followed the documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security

Following those instructions I end up with an application manifest that looks like this:

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Stateless1Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <Policies>
      <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="Cgud" />
    </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>

<Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="Cgud" AccountType="DomainUser" AccountName="Domain\UserName" Password="12345" />
    </Users>
</Principals>
```

I am currently sending the password in the clear just to try and get this working in the development environment, but will be encrypting it when moving to production.

We have tried running the Service Fabric Host Service as the default Local System user and a bare bones domain user and in both instances we get the error.

```
Error getting user account information for Doamin\userName: status=5, error=E_ACCESSDENIED
```

If I run the Host service as a domain admin account this error goes away and we get a new error about missing local security privileges for the domain admin account. I have worked out the local security policy issues, but there is NO chance we will run the Host Service as a domain admin in production.

The example looks very simple, but we have yet to get it to run using that simple example. We keep running into what looks to be domain permission issues and local security policy issues, none of which seem to be documented.

So finally to my questions.

1. Does anyone have a similar setup and run an application with services that RunAs a doamin user? If so, what user is running your Host Service and what domain rights and security privileges did you assign that user?
2. Is there any documentation about what rights and privileges are actually needed for the user running the Host Service to get an application service to RunAs a domain user?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you added the domain account to the ServiceFabricAllowedUsers group on the cluster machines?

Comment: Yes, I added the Account running the host service to both the Users and Admins groups and the user I want to RunAs is in the Users group.

Comment: There should be a specific group called ServiceFabricAllowedUsers - did you add the account to that group?

Comment: Yes. There are two local groups, ServiceFabricAllowedUsers and ServiceFabricAdministrators. They are the "Users" and "Admins" groups I was referring to above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I believe we have resolved the issue, although I still am uncertain of the root cause. I asked my network admin to spin up a completely new domain with a couple of clean server VMs. I installed everything from scratch in this new environment and it works perfectly right out of the box. I'm going to do a little more digging to see if I can identify the specific issue and I'll post back here.

Comment: Did you get any further with explaining this? I am experiencing the exact same issue. Thanks

Comment: It turns out we were using an unsupported version of Windows Server. We were using Server 2012, but the min version supported by Service Fabric is 2012 R2. So while it "ran" on 2012 it definitely did not work properly. The new VMs were 2021 R2 and so everything just worked.